# Rails: Throwing syntax errors for every curly bracket in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a functioning JavaScript program and if I paste the code directly into a Rails view, it works fine. When I place it in assets/javascript and call it with a javascript_include_tag, I start getting syntax errors for every occurrence of a curly bracket. For instance:

```
var rect = {};
```

throws an error, while:

```
var rect = new Object();
```

does not. Similarly, creating an object like this throws an error:

```
function tag(x, y, width, height){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.book = books[0];
}
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: the syntax error comes only if you have any curly bracket that either does not closed or added extra. if you have include more js file before this then check the sytax in those file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess but maybe you forgot to rename your javascript files that got generated for you?

As of Rails 3.1 it by default creates those files with the `.coffee` extension so it expects [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) to be written in them.

Simply try renaming them to `.js` instead of `.js.coffee` and it should work